# manage the number of outputs of a function in python

Tags: python, function, io, output

I want to make a function of returning the variable number of outputs.

I've tried `out1, out2 = function()[:-1]`and
`out1, out2 = function()[:2]` and
changing `function()` by using `if` statement

```
def function():
    a=1;b=2;c=3
    return a,b,c
out1, out2 = function() ### Line number 4
```

I want to do "Line number 4" only by changing `function()` without `if` statement.
`out1, out2 = function()`
Of course, this shows
`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: A function has exactly one return value. It can be a tuple, which is what you have in your code. It just looks like there are multiple return values due to some language features of Python. In this case the ability to define a tuple without parentheses and unpacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put several variables in the function call, instead of this:

```
out1, out2 = function()
```

do this:

```
values = function()
print "I've got", len(values), "return values"
```